# Setting A String To A .txt's File Contents?

Tags: c#, file

I want to set a string to the entire contents of a file without manually (with my own code) looping through the file and adding each line to the string.  Is there something built in that will accomplish this?

```
string asdf = file("aFile.txt");
```

Comment: you mean string asdf = File.ReadAllText("aFile.txt"); ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx). If you don't pass an encoding in, it will use UTF-8... but make sure that's actually what you want, or specify an encoding yourself.

Comment: Excellent, that's it thanks.  Also, you've answered a few questions of mine in the past and have been very helpful.  The other day, one of my superiors at work recommended to buy a book by a Jon Skeet called C# in depth.  I didn't realize you wrote a book, but yeah, that's pretty cool how you're involved in the community here.  I look forward to reading your book (it should be coming today).

Comment: @sooprise: Cool - hope you enjoy the book. Feel free to ask me any questions about it :)

Answer (score 3):

One of these:

```
    String FileStuff = File.ReadAllText("MyFile.txt");
    String[] FileLines = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt");
```